# What is Windows 10 Explorer Default font?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, fonts, evernote

I want to recreate the spacing in Windows 10 Explorer in Word and Evernote to create aligned text between 2 different file names.  To do this I used these characters to space words out in a pixel perfect fashion in Windows 10 Explorer:

1. U+0020 SPACE BAR
2. U+2003 EM SPACE (mutton)
3. U+2002 EN SPACE (nut)
4. U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE (thick space)
5. U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE (mid space)
6. U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
7. U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
8. U+2007 FIGURE SPACE

You can find all these unique characters [here](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html)

An example is this
[image]

If you copy the Windows 10 Explorer text into Word or Evernote, the "DL" text previously lined up perfectly is no longer aligned. Tried this with Segoe UI and Segoe. Some sources say Windows 7 uses a **different rendering engine** than Word to render the same font with very different spacing or kerning. I think Windows 10 does this too.

Some sources say the Windows 10 font is Segoe or Segoe UI. However the **spacing or kerning** is wrong for certain unicode characters in the list above.